# Conferir campo no banco

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo uma pesquisa no banco pra ver se o valor enviado já existe nele.

Esta é a função que estou utilizando:

```
 function buscaSubdominio($conexao, $nome_subdominio){

     $query = "select * from subdominio where nome_subdominio = ('{$nome_subdominio}')";
     return mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
   }
```

Então estou fazendo essa condição em outra página:

```
 $confere = buscaSubdominio($conexao, $nome_subdominio);

 if($confere == null){
   echo "registro inexistente";
 }
 else{
   echo "registro existente";
 }
```

Ele me devolve esse erro, podem me ajudar?

```
 Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_result::$nome_subdominio in C:\xampp   \htdocs\daLuz\subdominio.php on line 8
```

Comment: Ok, e qual é exatamente o problema ? Explique melhor a situação por favor. Não consegue fazer uma consulta pois o "usuário" está "deslogado" ?

Comment: Coloquei usuário deslogado por que ia perguntar de outra forma, mas esqueci de mudar. vou mudar o título. Este é o erro que vem, mas vou editar: Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_result::$nome_subdominio in C:\xampp\htdocs\daLuz\subdominio.php on line 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function buscaSubdominio($conexao, $nome_subdominio){

     $query = "select * from subdominio where nome_subdominio = ('{$nome_subdominio}')";
     $stmt = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
     $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($stmt);

     return $row_cnt;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Talvez seja porque a  variável `$nome_subdominio` não foi definida antes de ser usada na função.

Comment: ele está vindo via post

Comment: Então seria $_POST['nome_subdominio'] resultando em $confere = buscaSubdominio($conexao, $_POST['nome_subdominio');

Comment: sim @Sumback,  mas é assim eu só coloquei o if aí, mas antes eu pego ele no post e salvo na variavel $nome_subdominio

Comment: Ah sim, entendi. Tente dar um print_r na variável para ver se ela está entrando na função com algum valor e não vazia.

Comment: ele me devolve isso: mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 3 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 ), sabe o que posso fazer? eu programo a pouco tempo

Comment: Ele não esta retornando nenhuma linha ([num_rows] => 0). Tente fazer esse select direto no banco, caso funcione mas retorne linhas vazias, então pode ser que as tabelas estejam vazias.